# PHP keeps Inserting on refreshing

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am currently programming a website for a school project in which I have to organize daily schedules/reports.

Following Situation:
I am inserting the following into PHP:

```
$sqlinserttb = "INSERT INTO tagesberichte (`TbID`, `Tagesberichte`, `Datum`) VALUES ('DEFAULT', '".$tagesbericht."', '".$datum."');";
```

If submit has been hit, it inserts it. 
The problem is when I press F5 or manually refresh the browser, the page inserts it again with the last used inputs.

What did I miss?

Comment: not enough code to support the question; yet the solution is rather simple.

Comment: Where do you get $tagesbericht and $datum?

Comment: That's just what the browser does, it resends the post information if you refresh the post page. To prevent a user from doing this you can redirect the to the page again by name. Something like: `header("location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); exit();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `header("location: <path to your self-submitting form>");` after you are done inserting, that way a fresh form will be displayed and refreshing should not lead to submitting again.

Answer (score 0):

From the use case you explained, I understand that you have a self submitting form (submitting to the same page and handling request). You could store your request variables in [php sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and then check the incoming request data with that in the session (if session exists). If same, then display an error message, else do the insert and then set the session with your request data.

Comment: Yes, I it is a self submitting form, so I basically just start a session and then put all the SQL Inputs the user enters for example into the textarea into a session?

Comment: No. You first check if session exists. If exists, then compare that with request data. If all are same, then show error. Else, do the sql insert and then add the request data to the session.

Answer (score 0):

If your refresh the URL, all corresponding data will be sent to php script as it were posted by the user itself. To deal with it, you could:
1. Use post method to send result to the server. It will not exclude the situations with refresh of the page, but most browsers will ask the user "do you really want to resend all data to the server?"
2. Use redirect after the php script proceed the page with your input. In this case browser will not have the data to resend. But, the user could back to previos page still and resend the data again. 
3. Also you could provide some kind of 'meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" ... ' variables to make page expired

Comment: Hello, I am already sending it via post to the server and it does ask. Thanks for the hint with cache control, will look into it!