# PHP Keeps Inserting on Refresh

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, mysqli

I am currently working on registration for my app until I came upon this problem that whenever I go on to my page, it would create a new row in my `users` table. It seems that when I reload the page, the form would automatically submit. I had referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031148/php-keeps-inserting-on-refreshing) question:

> Use header("location: "); after you are done inserting, that way a fresh form will be displayed and refreshing should not lead to submitting again.

However, all that happened when I did that was a big redirect loop, preventing me from accessing the page all together.

Here is my code for my registration:

```
<?php 

    global $conn;
    global $register;
    global $error;

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

    define(HEADER_TITLE, "Register");
    include_once 'template/header.php';

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $register->register($username, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phone, $password, $confirmPassword);
    }

?>
<div class="container">
    <div id="hoogley_login">
        <h2>Register</h2><hr>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <?php
            if ($error->display() != null ) {
                #echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
                $error->display();
            } else {
                #echo '<div>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <form action="register" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_GET['firstName']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $_GET['lastName']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $_GET['phone']; ?>">
            <br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="register" value="Register!">
            <br><br>
            <a href="/login">Have an account? Login!</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



<?php include_once 'template/footer.php'; ?>
```

My register.class.php:

```
<?php


/**
* User Registration
*/
class register {

public function register($reg_username = '', $reg_firstName = '', $reg_lastName = '', $reg_email = '', $reg_phone = '', $reg_password = '', $reg_confirmPassword = '') {

    global $conn;
    global $error;

    // TO PREVENT AN UNDEFINED INDEX
    // First Name
    if(isset($reg_firstName)) {
        $reg_firstName = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_firstName)));
    } else {
        $error->set('312');
    }

    // Last Name
    if(isset($reg_lastName)) {
        $reg_lastName = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_lastName)));
    } else {
        $error->set('313');
    }

    // Username
    if(isset($reg_username)) {
        $reg_username = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_username))));
    } else {
        $error->set('311');
    }

    // Email
    if(isset($reg_email)) {
        $reg_email = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_email))));
    } else {
        $error->set('314');
    }

    // Phone
    if(isset($reg_phone)) {
        $reg_phone = stripslashes(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_phone))));
    } else {
        $error->set('315');
    }

    // Password
    if(isset($reg_password)) {
        $reg_password = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_password)));
    } else {
        $error->set('316');
    }

    // Password
    if(isset($reg_confirmPassword)) {
        $reg_password = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($conn->real_escape_string($reg_confirmPassword)));
    } else {
        $error->set('317');
    }

    // Check if username exists in the database
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $reg_username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $reg_email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone=?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $reg_phone);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {

                // Do passwords match?
                if ($reg_password == $reg_confirmPassword) {

                    $reg_passwordEncrypt = hash("sha256", $reg_password);

                    // Insert data
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, firstName, lastName, email, phone, password, company, website, bio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '', '', '')");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $reg_username, $reg_firstName, $reg_lastName, $reg_email, $reg_phone, $reg_passwordEncrypt);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    header("Location: /login");

                } else {
                    // Set Error
                    $error->set('308');
                }

            } else {
                // Set Error
                $error->set('306');
            }

        } else {
            // Set Error
            $error->set('304');
        }
    } else {
        // Set Error
        $error->set('301');

    }


}

}

$register = new register;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I remember when I used to handle my PHP code in the same file as my HTML forms... I had these sorts of problems all the time. Why not POST the information to a file specifically used for handling this? like a `process.php` file?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton When I did that I got some strange errors so I thought it was easier just to keep the PHP on the HTML as I only have a PHP function and some variables doing everything for me.

Comment: IMO it's way cleaner and easier to use another file, to prevent issues like the one you are having now :P

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I tried that, I gotten a weird error, I could maybe try to poke around in documentation a bit more.

Comment: Do you know what error specifically? If there is an error there is a fix!

Comment: '_However, all that happened when I did that was a big redirect loop_'. At what position in your code did you do this redirect? Should be just after `$register->register()` within the `if`-statement (or within the `register`-method).

Comment: You should clarify a couple things.  First, "whenever I go on to my page, it would create a new row in my users table". It would create the row simply by you visiting the page? Or you had to visit, submit, and then reload? These are very different. Second, "all that happened when I did that was a big redirect loop, preventing me from accessing the page all together.". Basically the same thing. When were you infinitely redirected? When you just tried to visit the page at all? Or only after submitting?

Comment: @PatrickQ Whenever I go on the page or refresh it, it would insert a new row into my table every time the page is loaded. Preventing me from accessing the page was the redirection loop.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton There was no error, it just created a new row every time the page loaded.

Comment: @PetervanderWal Sorry if this was confusing, but I referred to the question(linked above) and it said to header it to a different location after it is done. What happened was I was infinitely redirected.

Comment: In development, the more your logics are good, the better output you will get. An HTML form submits user's data to an action script. Logically these are supposed to be two different files. In addition to this, remember to have all your action scripts separated and away from your HTML/PHP pages that user views.

Comment: Guess I totally misunderstood your question/problem... sorry for my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have same name for method as class name. It is working as PHP 4 constructor and it is calling the method when initializing the object.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_php4_constructors